# Update nested bigquery json element

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, nested, sql-update

I have a big-query schema such as this:

```
visitorId                    INTEGER NULLABLE
visitID                      INTEGER NULLABLE
hits                         RECORD  REPEATED
hits.eventInfo               RECORD  NULLABLE   
hits.eventInfo.eventCategory STRING  NULLABLE   
hits.eventInfo.eventLabel    STRING  NULLABLE
```

with sample data as:

```
visitorId  visitId  hits.eventInfo.eventCategory hits.eventInfo.eventCategory
123456     1        abc                          {"info":"secret", "otherfields":"blah"}
                    lmn                          {"info":"secret", "otherfields":"blah"}
                    xyz                          {"info":"secret", "otherfields":"blah"}
124557     1        abc                          {"info":"secret", "otherfields":"blah"}
                    lmn                          {"info":"secret", "otherfields":"blah"}
                    xyz                          {"info":"secret", "otherfields":"blah"}
```

I need to remove **"info":"secret",** only when the eventCategory is **"abc"**.

I am a big-query newbie. After much hitting and trying I was able to come to this, but unfortunately stuck now.

```
UPDATE `project.dataset.ga_sessions_20200608`
SET hits = ARRAY(
  SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE((REGEXP_REPLACE(eventInfo.eventLabel, r"\"info\":\"[a-z A-Z]*\",", "")) AS eventInfo.eventLabel) from UNNEST(hits) 
)
WHERE (select eventInfo.eventLabel from UNNEST(hits)) LIKE '%info%'
```

There are two problems here.

- set part is not working :(
- subquery in where (subselect) is not giving a scalar output :'(

Any help, pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi! Could you please provide the json file with the data, ready to load into bigquery? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's challenging to do this with DML approach (`UPDATE`) as opposed to a batch process that operates over the whole table for a few reasons (some of which you already gave):

- The subfields within the records that need updating are JSON string-ified
- The nature of the update is a filter by field key in the string representation
- The records themselves are repeated type at top level of the table, and contain structs

This puts you in the position of having to reconstruct the entire struct of both `hits` and `eventInfo` in order to replace it's one field (which is itself a JSON encoded struct, although BigQuery is sort of blind to this and treats it as a string).

AFAIK BigQuery does not have a function that marshalls a true STRUCT from json, so regex might be the only way to actually eliminate the undesired field in the json-encoded column.

The WHERE condition here can make use of the `JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR` standardSQL function to capture the condition that the particular key to be removed actually exists in the json.

So a possible pure BigQuery approach (no UDFs) could look like:

```
#standardSQL
UPDATE
  `project.dataset.table_DATE`
SET
  --reconstruct hits column as an array
  hits = ARRAY(
  SELECT
       --reconstruct each struct of hits
    AS STRUCT * REPLACE( (
      SELECT
        --reconstruct eventInfo...
        AS STRUCT eventInfo.* REPLACE(
          --with eventLabel replaced with a filtered version
          REGEXP_REPLACE(eventInfo.eventLabel, r"\"secret\":\"[A-Za-z\p{L}]* [A-Za-z\p{L}]*\",", "") AS eventLabel)
        ) AS eventInfo )
  FROM
    UNNEST(hits) AS hits )
WHERE
  --Only for rows where at least one eventLabel's json contains a `secret` key
  EXISTS (SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(h.eventInfo.eventLabel, "$.secret") is not null from unnest(hits) as h)
```

Note the regex there may need some changes based on the format of the data.  Here I'm assuming a two word secret value with possible unicode characters (like a first + last name).

The regex part might be better served by a [UDF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions), although those can be slow for large table.

Comment: Thank you, very close to what I wanted. I will retrofit this to my requirements.